# How to control log-message level for user Jobs/Tasks in Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop

I need to print trace and debug messages from my hadoop mapreduce job, while keeping hadoop system messages at the default level (INFO by default).

I tried the following:

In the Job methods added logger message:

```
package org.example.mapreducejob

public void reduce(Text extId, Iterable<MyData>> myDataItems, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    log.debug("reduce(): i want this message to be printed in the userlogs");
    log.info("reduce(): Info message");
    ...
}
```

Then in $HADOOP_HOME/conf/log4.properties I added the line:
`log4j.logger.com.terapeak.etl=DEBUG`

and restarted the node

However only "Info message' appears in user logs. 
Where should I change logger configuration to enable DEBUG messages for user jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. In the $HADOOP_HOME/conf there are two config files for log4.properties:

```
log4j.properties
task-log4j.properties
```

To change log level for user jobs you need to make changes in `task-log4j.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop = DEBUG
```